# How to add a new dict with 2 different types into a new array in julia

Tags: julia

How can I add a dict with 2 different field types (1D array of float and float) to an array nested in a dict that already exists?

The 'allmeas' structure already exists up to this point:

```
allmeas[measkey]["manreps"][num_manrep]
```

And I'm trying to add like this:

```
allmeas[measkey]["manreps"][num_manrep]["autoreps"] = Array{Dict{Any,Any},1}  

num_autorep = 1
meas_1D_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
meas_single_value = 10

newmeas = {"meas_1D_array"=> meas_1D_array ,"meas_single_value"=> meas_single_value}

allmeas[measkey]["manreps"][num_manrep]["autoreps"][num_autorep] = newmeas
```

The error I get is on the last line:

```
`setindex!` has no method matching setindex!(::Type{Array{Dict{Any,Any},1}}, ::Dict{Any,Any}, ::Int64)
```

If I look at the types of each side, I get:

```
typeof(allmeas[measkey]["manreps"][num_manrep]["autoreps"]) is Array{Dict{Any,Any},1}
typeof(newmeas) is Dict{Any,Any}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `Array{Dict{Any,Any},1}` is a *type*, where the `1` denotes the number of dimensions. You meant for it to be an uninitialized array with length 1. Try replacing it with `Array(Dict{Any, Any}, 1)`. See [the Array construction section of the manual](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.3/manual/arrays/#construction-and-initialization).

Replacing `allmeas[measkey]["manreps"][num_manrep]["autoreps"]` with `x` in your example:

```
julia> x = Array(Dict{Any, Any}, 1)
1-element Array{Dict{Any,Any},1}:
#undef

julia> newmeas = {"meas_1D_array"=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "meas_single_value"=> 10}
Dict{Any,Any} with 2 entries:
  "meas_single_value" => 10
  "meas_1D_array"     => [1,2,3,4,5,6]

julia> x[1] = newmeas;

julia> x
1-element Array{Dict{Any,Any},1}:
 {"meas_single_value"=>10,"meas_1D_array"=>[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
```

The syntax for the type and the array initialization are very similar, so it's an easy mistake to make. It helps to think of curly braces as always being about *types*. The exception is that in Julia 0.3, you can create arrays and dictionaries with `{1, 2, 3}`. However, this behavior will be deprecated in the soon-to-be-released Julia 0.4.

Comment: Ah! I hadn't appreciated that difference. Thanks! The change in 0.4 seems like a good clarification